# Is there a way to generate and collect objects -on the fly- with a stream of another type?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I need to create a new set of `objects(synsets)` from a stream of Strings, then collect them in a `HashSet`. I'm trying to do this in a `.forEach` to avoid collecting the strings and then create the `objects(synsets)` for each of the strings and then collecting them again in a set.

```
try (Stream<String> reader = Files.lines(Path)) {
    reader.filter(s -> !s.startsWith(" "))
            .forEach(set.add(new Synset(s)));
}
```

Comment: You can use the `Stream#map` method which allows you to transform `Stream<X>` lazily into `Stream<Y>`. And then you can collect into whatever you want using `collect(...)` or just execute whatever you want with `forEach(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a set, where you want to add the objects to, I would do it like this:

```
try (Stream<String> reader = Files.lines(Paths.get("path-to-file"))) {
    reader.filter(s -> !s.startsWith(" "))
            .map(Synset::new)
            .forEach(set::add);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use collect as:

```
try (Stream<String> reader = Files.lines(Paths.get(<file paths>))) {
    Set<Synset> set = reader.filter(s -> !s.startsWith(" "))
            .map(Synset::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: In your current code as well, there is a minor correction required in the lambda as `forEach(s -> set.add(new Synset(s))`